# PhoneGap iOS app fails to resume in time

Tags: ios, cordova

I am creating a **PhoneGap** app that, when the app is active, is tracking the user's current location and showing it on a map.

When the app starts I start tracking the location using `setInterval` on `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`. When I receive the *pause* event, that interval is cleared. When I get the *resume* event, I call `setInterval` again.

Also, on receiving a *resume* event, I need to send an Ajax request to the server to see if anything interesting has happened while the app was in the background, and perhaps display a new screen with information as a result.

Sometimes, almost never on my phone, but more frequently on a tester's phone, the resume is taking too much time and the app is killed by iOS:

```
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-05-29 09:26:54.352 +0200
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.4 (10B350)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
com.x failed to resume in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 10.590 (user 10.590, system 0.000), 53% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 9.821, 49% CPU
```

The following pseudo code shows how I have wired the app:

```
(function app() {

    function init() {
        // Init app
        // ...

        startGPS();

        checkState();
    }

    function checkState() {
        // Make Ajax request to server and compare with local state
        // and decide which screen to show
        // ...
    }

    function startGPS() {
        // use setInterval on navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
        // ...
    }

    function stopGPS() {
        // clear the interval from startGPS()
        // ...
    }

    // Other functions
    // ...

    on('pause', stopGPS);
    on('resume', startGPS)
    on('resume', checkState);
    on('deviceready', init);

})();
```

I, perhaps naïvely, believed that since both the Ajax call and the `getCurrentPosition` call are async I wouldn't lock up the rendering and the app would be able to resume in time, but it doesn't seem to be that way. I also tried to wrap my *resume* code in a `setTimeout`, but with the same result.

What would be a better approach to achieve this without failing to resume in time?

I am using PhoneGap 2.7

Answer (score 0):

You could try running the startGPS() and checkState() functions synchronously by waiting for one to return before calling the other. Try it both ways around as maybe one of those two functions is hammering the CPU causing your app to get killed:

```
function startGPS() {
  // use setInterval on navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
}
function checkState(){
  $.ajax({
    url: someurl,
    success: function(){
      // Make Ajax request to server and compare with local state
      startGPS();
    }
  });
}
on('resume', checkState);
```

or

```
function startGPS() {
  var firstCall = true;
  setInterval(function(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
      // do some stuff with position...

      if(firstCall){
        firstCall = false;
        checkState(); // check state after first successful position is returned
      }
    });
  }, someInterval);
}
function checkState(){
  // Make Ajax request to server and compare with local state
}
on('resume', startGPS);
```